# VOIP Library for Mobile(Android/IOS) and Web Application

Tags: android, ios, web-applications, webrtc, void

*I don't know it is suitable place for this question or not, if this is not the right place please redirect me to the right one. i am asking this question after spending 3-4 days. Please be with me.*

I have a web app/Mobile app(Android and iOS) something like small ERP application. We want audio calling feature for the application, we have been looking for days but didn't get a suitable solution.

Our Requirement is 
Browser - Browser Calling,
App to browser,
App to App,
browser to app

we don't need internet to phone feature. Ultimately we are looking for a solution that will allow user to call directly without knowing the phone number.

In my research i came across WebRTC, but didn't understand the logic.

so if there is any way (library or something) (free/paid), any kind of information will be helpful (article/library/webpage/explanation). To give me a path to move forward with the research.

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Paid Library :**

1) Zipper -- It has native  sdk for mobile and Javascript sdk for mobile or web.  https://www.zoiper.com/en/voip-sdk

2) ToxBox is also good library for voice call. https://tokbox.com/

**Open Source :**

Try Linphone-  Its good for voice calling - they also provide sdk for Mobile and web.

https://www.linphone.org

Answer (score 0):

**Open Source**
http://www.pjsip.org/ - SIP platform based